# Cassandra nodes failing on heavy writes

Tags: c#, linq, cassandra

I am new to Cassandra and testing it for write loads, but am having issues with Cassandra stability.  First, a bit of information about the environment:

- Windows (tested on PCs with Windows 7 and 8, as well as Server 2008 R2 and Server 2012)
- Using Java 7 u 45 (the latest available at the time of writing this question)
- Cassandra 1.2.10
- Accessing Cassandra with the Cassandra C# 1.01 driver
- Issue occurs no matter the size of the cluster (testing from 1 node up to 6 nodes in a cluster).
- Disk for data is a SSD.

The application I am writing will be dealing with extremely large datasets of information, requiring the high write (and read) capabilities for which Cassandra is known.

**The Example**

The example I am using creates a "test" object with four fields: ID (GUID), Name (Text), Insert_User (Text), and Insert_TimeStamp (TimeStamp).  The code simply attempts to create 1 million records in batches of 50,000.  Generally, the write process fails when reaching 150,000 to 200,000 records.  Most of the time, the write timeout exception occurs (timeout set for 20 seconds).  Sometimes, the heap overflows, but I seem to have solved that problem by adjusting the cache and flush settings in the cassandra.yaml file as well as expanding the heap with the following Java configuration settings:

```
-Xmx20G -Xms1G -Xss256K
```

The code I am using is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Cassandra;
using Cassandra.Data.Linq;

namespace TestLinq3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WindowWidth = 160;

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Started at " + System.DateTime.Now);

            var cluster = Cluster.Builder()
                        .AddContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
                        .WithCredentials("cassandra", "cassandra")
                        .Build();

            Metadata metadata = cluster.Metadata;

            Console.WriteLine("Starting process...");

            var session = cluster.Connect();
            session.CreateKeyspaceIfNotExists("test");
            session.ChangeKeyspace("test");

            Console.WriteLine("Connected to keyspace...");

            var table = session.GetTable<Test>();
            table.CreateIfNotExists();

            List<Test> testlist = new List<Test>();

            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Running j loop " + j.ToString());

                var batch = session.CreateBatch();

                for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
                {
                    testlist.Add(new Test { id = System.Guid.NewGuid(), name = "Name " + i, insertUser = "cassandra", insertTimeStamp = System.DateTimeOffset.UtcNow });
                }

                batch.Append(from t in testlist select table.Insert(t));

                try
                {
                    batch.Execute();
                    //Flush();
                }
                catch (WriteTimeoutException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("WriteTimeoutException hit.  Waiting 20 seconds...");
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
                }

                batch = null;

                Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed since start is " + sw.Elapsed.Hours.ToString("00")+":"+sw.Elapsed.Minutes.ToString("00")+":"+sw.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString("00"));
            }

            var results = (from rows in table where rows.name == "Name 333" select rows).Execute().Count();

            Console.WriteLine(results);

            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Processing time was " + sw.Elapsed.Hours.ToString("00") + ":" + sw.Elapsed.Minutes.ToString("00") + ":" + sw.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString("00") + ":" + sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString("00") + ".");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        [AllowFiltering]
        [Table("test")]
        public class Test
        {
            [PartitionKey]
            [Column("id")]
            public Guid id;
            [SecondaryIndex]
            [Column("name")]
            public string name;
            [SecondaryIndex]
            [Column("insert_user")]
            public string insertUser;
            [SecondaryIndex]
            [Column("insert_timestamp")]
            public DateTimeOffset insertTimeStamp;
        }
    }
}
```

The Cassandra.yaml settings I have are here (comments removed in order to save space):

```
#Cassandra storage config YAML
cluster_name: 'DEV'
initial_token:
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000 # 3 hours
hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
max_hints_delivery_threads: 2
authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator
authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer
permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
data_file_directories:
    - /var/lib/cassandra/data
commitlog_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
disk_failure_policy: stop
key_cache_size_in_mb:
key_cache_save_period: 14400
row_cache_size_in_mb: 0
row_cache_save_period: 0
row_cache_provider: SerializingCacheProvider
saved_caches_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000
commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32
seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
        - seeds: "127.0.0.1"
flush_largest_memtables_at: 0.50
reduce_cache_sizes_at: 0.50
reduce_cache_capacity_to: 0.30
concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32
memtable_total_space_in_mb: 4096
memtable_flush_writers: 8
memtable_flush_queue_size: 4
trickle_fsync: false
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240
storage_port: 7000
ssl_storage_port: 7001
listen_address: localhost
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
start_rpc: true
rpc_address: localhost
rpc_port: 9160
rpc_keepalive: true
rpc_server_type: sync
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15
incremental_backups: false
snapshot_before_compaction: false
auto_snapshot: true
column_index_size_in_kb: 64
in_memory_compaction_limit_in_mb: 64
multithreaded_compaction: false
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16
compaction_preheat_key_cache: true
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
cross_node_timeout: false
endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1
request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler
index_interval: 128
server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    truststore: conf/.truststore
    truststore_password: cassandra
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
internode_compression: all
inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: true
```

The goal of this effort is to have the Cassandra nodes be stable, even if that requires having a slower write pace per node (current write speed is around 7,000 records per second).  After searching StackOverflow and other locations on the internet, I have not found the correct fix for this issue, and would appreciate any feedback from those with Cassandra experience in high write volume environments.

Best,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

What do the logs say? Do you see this error: *Heap is 89.2615008651467% full. You may need to reduce memtable and/or cache sizes.*

If so the culprit is probably [CASSANDRA-6107](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6107). The problem was prepared statements were getting cached but the limit for how many queries could be cached was too high and didn't take account of the size of each statement (if you did a batched statement it would be much higher than a simple select) and this was exhausting the node's memory. Also since the statement was cached, it wouldn't be removed by GC leading to OOM errors.

Comment: I tried a number of different adjustments with the memtable and cache sizes.  Still no luck.  The issue is the application I am writing requires a huge number of writes each evening.